# svg animation browser support

Tags: css, animation, svg, cross-browser

I want to dive into the wonderful world of .svg animation for the website I'm working for.

I'm looking to do an icon that animates on hover. I have found multiple tutorials that can all help me out, however, I noticed that there are a lot of different ways to achieve an svg animation.

I can find very little info on what is the most supported way to animate an svg. Is it with a js library? The animate tag? css animation?

A js library seems best to me, but I like the idea of using css as well. Can someone tell me more about the browser support of these methods?

Comment: On [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) there is compatibility table

Comment: I think it depends on the complexity of the animation. If its basic, there's no need to use a big svg library. Just use css. If its quite complex, then look at one of the libraries like Snap, svg.js. I wouldn't bother with the animate tag these days, as there's typically some issue somewhere that crops up that wastes up some time.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots plugins are available to animate svg.few are listed here

- [snapsvg](http://snapsvg.io/)
- [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)
- [segmentjs](https://lmgonzalves.github.io/segment/)

you can checkout crossbrowser compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).